# Android Imageview "squeezed" by TextView

Tags: android, textview, imageview, width

I have defined an XML to show a little popUp window:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
    android:background="@drawable/marker_popup_border"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="5dip"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tracks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/popUpName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/popUpState"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/graylightmore" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/info"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/info" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow_down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-4dip"
    android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_black" />
```

When one of the two Textviews requires a lot of space, the info-image gets squeezed...you can see the result on [this](http://www.emaborsa.com/jpg/screen2.png) link. I'd need a hint in order that the i is always displayed and the textviews are devided into 2 rows if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving layout_weight property as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
    android:background="@drawable/marker_popup_border"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="5dip"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tracks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" 
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/popUpName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/popUpState"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/graylightmore" 
            >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/info"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/info" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow_down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-4dip"
    android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_black" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually giving the weights the i doesn't get squeezed, however, the popup results different. Give me some time and i'll show you what i mean...

Comment: [Here](http://www.emaborsa.com/jpg/textView.jpg) you can see that the popup window result different, which depend by the textview.

Comment: Ok. I see. And I think, it's not a good idea to give static width for imageview! Can you make your parent layout tracks relative layout?

Comment: i'm the same opinion, not to do static width. I also tried to change the layout to a relative layout, but then the popup window always takes as width the screen width.

Comment: Well, if you mean android:layout_width="0dp" it's instead of "wrap content"...suggested by Eclipse.

Comment: another strange thing: When i run the app in debug from Eclipse the popupwindow is wrapping the content. when i install the app from the google paly (which is the exact same code version) the window is streching over the screen width...how is it possible?

Comment: That's really strange. I think that should not happen